# Hiding all the 'Skipped Build' messages in VS2005 / VS2008

Tags: build, visual-studio-2008

I'm building a Visual C++ solution that includes a large number of projects, most of which are skipped for this build.  Every time I hit 'Build' I get a dozen messages like this in the Build output:

1>------ Skipped Build: Project: this_project_name, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
2>------ Skipped Build: Project: another_project, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
3>------ Skipped Build: Project: skipped_this_one, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
3>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
4>------ Skipped Build: Project: yep_did_nothing, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
[..snip!..]
18>------ Skipped Build: Project: screen_full_of_spam, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
18>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration
19>------ Skipped Build: Project: the_scrollbar_is_tiny, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
19>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

Is there a way to suppress these 'I did nothing' messages that the IDE is giving me?  I prefer just to see items in the Build window that the compiler DID do.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no way to suppress the messages:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/465132/project-not-selected-to-build-for-this-solution-configuration-messages-cannot-be-suppressed#tabs

Maybe if enough people vote it up, they'll reopen it.